# No repositories in RedHat (via VMWARE)

Tags: package-management, yum, repository

I have installed a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 on VMWARE. I am unable to find any repositories. I want to perform the following

-> `yum groupinstall virtualization "virtualization client" "virtualization platform" "virtualization tools"`

But Linux returns me an error that no packages exist.

Is there any way I can download all repositories from torrent or something & install it?

Comment: Is your domain lookup working properly?

Comment: what happens when you do "yum update" ?

Comment: @Abey: "No Packages marked for Update"

Comment: @DanPipe What happens if you split the commands and do this `yum groupinstall "Virtualization" -y && yum groupinstall "Virtualization Client" -y  &&  yum groupinstall "Virtualization Platform" -y  &&  yum groupinstall "Virtualization Tools" -y `

Comment: May I ask why you installed RHEL 6 (from 2010) rather than RHEL 7 (from 2014)?

The package groups you are looking for might not be available on your older release.

You could also try installing the EPEL repositories (https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Answer (score 0):

You should try again with the proper casing for the package groups:

```
 yum groupinstall Virtualization "Virtualization Tools" "Virtualization Platform" "Virtualization Client"
```

Comment: Still didn't work.  Error "No packages in any requested group available to install or update"